# allow only numbers AND may 'contain' slash AND must not start or end with slash

Tags: regex

what I have is this:

```
[^\/][\d]*[^\/]
```

The problem I still have is: slash at the beginning is still allowed

Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many `/`s can there be? 1 or more? Can there be multiple consecutive `/`s? What is the regex flavor - does it support lookaheads/lookbehinds?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yesmultiple / are allowed. also consecutive / s. the engine does support lookaheads/lookbehinds

Comment: Ok, I added an answer with two solutions, one with lookarounds and another without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[^/]` matches any char, not just a digit. Besides, to validate a whole string, you need to use anchors, or a method that anchors the match at start and end of the string.

You may use

```
^(?!\/)[\d\/]*$(?<!\/)
```

Or

```
^\d(?:[\/\d]*\d)?$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/8RAmDD/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/8RAmDD/2).

**Regex #1 details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\/)` - no  `/` allowed at the start
- `[\d\/]*` - 0 or more digits or slashes
- `$`- end of string
- `(?<!\/)` - fail the match if there is a `/` at the end.

**Regex #2 details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:[\/\d]*\d)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 0 or more `/` or digit chars and then a digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thank you very much Wiktor, this was driving me crazy

Comment: Very nice with the lookarounds ++

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
(^[\d]$|^[\d][\/\d]*[\d]$)
```

Look [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/1) here

```
^[\d] --- start with digit
[\/\d]* --- / or digit can be 0 or more times
[\d]$ --- end with digit
```

One more case for 1 digit only:

```
^[\d]$ --- start and end digit only
```

Comment: i like the straight forwardness of your solution ^^